# Shoulda use shoulda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda, thoughtbot

We are currently using thoughtbots [shoulda gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) mostly to spec functionality of our rails models.

It appears that a lot of the matchers that shoulda provides are actually testing **rails behaviour**. E.g.

```
describe Blog do
  it { should have_many(:posts) }
end
```

just tests that this code from the model definition

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

actually works.

Isn't this testing **rails behavior** (as opposed to the behaviour of our models)?
Isn't this something to avoid generally?

Comment: imaging `posts` is used somewhere in your app and somebody removed `has_many :posts`, without test you won't know there is problem until your app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of question can easily derive into a flame war, but anyway, I'll give my two cents.

I do use shoulda matchers most of the times, and I agree with you that these kind of tests may look superfluous at first. So why do I keep using them?

When you're doing BDD, you are not testing the single units, but you're actually testing an object *Behavior*. In my point of view knowing that a `Blog` entity responds to a `posts` method with a collection of many `posts`, is part of the behavior of the `Blog` class. So I want to test it.

Further, if you follow the TDD cycle strictly, you cannot theoretically add the

```
has_many :posts
```

line without violating the principle that you should write a test first.

As in many other areas, the definitive answer depends on the project. If you have a large project with many models (or a project that is growing to be such), you may really want to test the interfaces.

If you just have a `Post` model with an `Author`, it may look like an overkill. But in this case it would cost you something like 4 lines of test... so why not?